# i want an upvote button that when clicked increment the value of a field(integer) in database

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications, django-templates

my html for button is

```
<td>
  <a href="{% url 'minor:upvote'  %}">
    <button type="button" class="likes" style="text-align:center;border-radius:40px;width: 100px;height: 40px">upvote</button>
  </a>
</td>
```

url is..

```
path('',view=views.upv,name='upvote'),
```

view is

```
def upv(request,id):
    reporter = Logg.objects.get(id=id)
    reporter.upvote = reporter.upvote+1
    reporter.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

but the upvote field i.e an integer field with default value 0 is not getting incremented.

Comment: i think it has do something with id,

Comment: print upvote after and before "reporter.upvote = reporter.upvote+1" this line. check if this line is working

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass id in the `urlpatterns` definition. Since you use `path`, to add id into your view argument use this

```
path('<id>/', views.upv, name="upvote")
```

From the `path` documentation

> The route argument should be a string or gettext_lazy() (see Translating URL patterns) that contains a URL pattern. ***The string may contain angle brackets (like  above) to capture part of the URL and send it as a keyword argument to the view.***

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path

and then in the template you also need to include the id

```
<td>
  <a href="{% url 'minor:upvote' id=logg.id  %}">
    <button type="button" class="likes" style="text-align:center;border-radius:40px;width: 100px;height: 40px">upvote</button>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: But sir what about the html template,it must also be edited then .

Comment: thanks now it is working i added Logg.id in template also.

Comment: Cool, glad I can help you

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `Logg` ID to the view, add a numberic parameter to the URL and pass the ID to the `url` templatetag:

URL route:

```py
path('(?P<id>\d+)',view=views.upv,name='upvote'),
```

Template:

```
{% url 'minor:upvote' my_current_logg.pk %}
```

Comment: Cool, please accept the answer if it solved your issue